# connectionstring for sql server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 with a windows form aplication with the app.config file in XML=1.0 using this connection string

```
Server=10.217.192.130;Database=CanDB;User Id=CW01\uidv7832;Password=mypass!;
```

and it gives out this error :

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please check the inner exception to find out what the *actual* problem is, just in case it's not the connection string? =)

Comment: which EF? code first? or "full"? or...? also: what key are you using in the app.config? i.e. what is the name of this connection-string name/value pair?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Connect SQL server through server explorer from view (menu bar) in VS. Then from its property you will get the corresponding connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new ".udl" file (universal data link) to check if the connection string it creates matches the connection string you are using.

Follow [this step-by-step MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to know how to create a .udl file, then open it with notepad to see the connection string.